# Abstraction in OOPs

Tags: java, c++, oop

I have come across few definitions over the years, and have never able to clearly understand what abstraction is.
I have understood the 3 main concepts of Oops but have had difficulties with this particular concept which is engraved within these other concepts.

Till now i have come to 2 conclusions, but not sure.

- It is the ability to hide the implementation details of a method(Behavior), and provide the user with just the interface.
- It is ability to define a method signatures(ie. only to declare them) without actually implementing them.

Which is the correct definition of abstraction with context to Object oriented programming, and if not one of the above, then what is it?

Would appreciate if supporting code is also provided :)

Comment: Abstraction is probably too complex a word; how about fruit? Bananas are a fruit. Apples are a fruit. The word fruit is an *abstraction* for a kind of vegetable that people find sweet.

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29#Abstraction_in_object_oriented_programming

Comment: Abstraction means `Generalization`. Like `Fruit` is an abstract entity but in real world there is no concrete entity called fruit; rather it's more specific type of fruit. Similarly, `vehicle` is an abstract entity and in real world there present only most specific type of vehicle entity.

Comment: One of my favourite essays about abstraction is [Zed Shaw's](http://www.zedshaw.com/essays/indirection_is_not_abstraction.html).

Comment: @Rahul : i don't agree : abstraction does not necessarily mean generalization : a skyscraper is a building (generalization), and both can be built / instantiated. Abstraction is about regrouping behaviours without allowing direct instantiation / usage. Abstraction needs a concrete implementation, while a generalization does not necessarily require it.

Comment: @kraal, yes abstract entity can be instantiated (unless marked as `abstract`) but instantiating them won't make any sense since those are just abstract concept and have no real world resemblance.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: "The word fruit is an abstraction for a kind of vegetable that people find sweet." Technically wrong. In both culinary and botanical use, fruit is a seed-containing organ produced by a plant. In culinary use it is also edible and sweet. Vegetables are edible plant parts not necessarily containing seeds. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetable#Terminology And I wouldn't call it an abstraction in any case.

Comment: A better example would be that a binary operation is an abstraction of multiplication, addition, subtraction, division, etc.

Comment: @JasonS Sorry, actually there is no technical (culinary or botanical) distinction between a fruit and a vegetable. Per your example, strawberries wouldn't be fruits (because the seeds are on the outside of the body) while tomatoes and cucumbers would be (because the seeds are on the inside of the body).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is the ability to hide the implementation details of a method(Behavior), and provide the user with just the interface.

*Sort of*, but that's "encapsulation".  They're *related* in the sense that "encapsulation" is a key concept of object oriented design whereas "abstraction" is a potential result of that concept.

> It is ability to define a method signatures(ie. only to declare them) without actually implementing them.

That's an implementation detail, not the conceptual notion of abstraction itself.

In a simple inheritance model, "abstraction" can be thought of as referring to an object by one of its ancestor (or more abstract) types.  For example, consider a hierarchy:

```
Lifeform
Animal
Canine
Golden Retriever
```

If you're performing an operation specific only to a Golden Retriever, then you can't perform that operation on *any* Animal.  It has to be a *specific* Animal.  So you need that specific implementation.

However, if you're performing an operation that's generic to all Lifeforms then it doesn't matter what specific implementation you receive.  That operation is abstracted so that it can accept any `Lifeform` object, regardless of the more specific implementation.

Interfaces provide another implementation mechanism which can achieve abstractions.  Object composition is still another mechanism.  For example, consider this non-inheritance scenario:

```
public class MyObject {
    private ThirdPartyObject dependency;

    public MyObject() {
        // initialize the dependency
    }

    public boolean getValue() {
        return this.dependency.getValue();
    }

    public void setValue(boolean value) {
        this.dependency.setValue(value);
    }
}
```

This doesn't use inheritance or interfaces for anything, but it does create an *abstraction*.  Consuming code doesn't know anything about the `ThirdPartyObject` or the details of its implementation.  Following the [Law Of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) the details of that implementation have been abstracted behind a custom object which you control.  This can be very useful for de-coupling your code from implementation details you don't control.

Comment: As is, your example is more about generalization/specialization rather than about abstraction. What is important is that if a class cannot be instantiated then it is abstract. In your example, you cannot "instantiate" a Lifeform, but you can "instantiate" a Golden Retriever. However the Life Form class provides the die() behaviour (but not necessarily defines how an Animal, Canine, or Golden Retriver will die())

Comment: @kraal: Usually, but not necessarily.  You're right, in my example one would never instantiate a Lifeform.  Other inheritance hierarchies could easily differ in that regard.  The higher level is still the more abstract one, but as an implementation detail could still be a concrete class.

Answer (score 1):

> **Abstraction is a process where you show only “relevant” data and “hide” unnecessary details of an object from the user.**
>
> - For example, when you login to your Amazon account online, you enter
>   your user_id and password and press login, what happens when you press
>   login, how the input data sent to amazon server, how it gets verified
>   is all abstracted away from the you.
> - Another example of abstraction: A car in itself is a well-defined
>   object, which is composed of several other smaller objects like a
>   gearing system, steering mechanism, engine, which are again have their
>   own subsystems. But for humans car is a one single object, which can be managed by the help of its subsystems, even if their inner details
>   are unknown.
>
> Also to be noted that abstraction hides the implementation  details but implementation can be shown even i.e. member functions with definitions can also be present, unlike *Interface* which provides total *Abstraction*.

Source: [BeginnersBook.com](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/oops-in-java-encapsulation-inheritance-polymorphism-abstraction/)

Answer (score 0):

My summary is "hiding the details"; in the case of programming, abstraction is more like your first definition.

For supporting code, you don't really need to look too far. Abstraction is all around. Consider the common data structure `string`.

A string within a computer is actually bytes converted to a specific character set strung together. (no pun intended)

Therefore, when you put `"hello, world"` to you, it's a phrase in quotes. When the computer run it, it creates a data structure `string` which itself contains the bytes and various state to represent the given string.  **You don't (usually) care how the `string` object is working.** It does and you move on with your goal. That is as basic of an example of abstraction as I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Abstraction is the process by which data and programs are defined with a representation similar in form to its meaning, while hiding away the implementation details.Abstraction involves the facility to define objects that represent abstract “actors” that can perform work, report on and change their state, and “communicate” with other objects in the system.

Abstraction can be seen in two ways:

Data Abstraction - Data abstraction is the way to create complex data types and exposing only meaningful operations to interact with data type, where as hiding all the implementation details from outside works.

Control Abstraction - Abstraction of behavior. Provides an easier, higher level API to hide client from unnecessary execution details.

Comment: Doesn't hiding the implementation details using teh access specifiers etc. the definition of encapsulation?

Answer (score 0):

Abstraction is a way to promise that a class implementing a given abstraction will have a given behaviour. Thus, abstract classes cannot be directly instantiated, they first need to implement the abstraction.

Abstract classes are thus meant to be implemented by a concrete class that declares and defines a method matching the abstract contract. An abstraction can however provide some concrete behaviours along with abstract ones.

Abstraction is done in Java through `abstract` classes and through `interface`. In C++, abstraction is achieved through the usage of `virtual` methods inside a class. Note that Java interfaces were only created as (unlike C++) multiple inheritance is not allowed in this language.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms

Abstraction: Showing what is necessary and hiding unnecessary details. Ex if your class has 10 functions but only 2 should be useful by the consumer of the class that you make those functions as public and other are private, so what is visible to the consumer is what is needed, instead of showing it all.

Encapsulation: Hiding the complexity to the consumer of the class. Ex. if your class needs two variables to store min and max, you encapsulate them under getter and setter and implement all the validations and checks in the getter and setter. this  way you hide the complexities.

Answer (score 0):

Well I will explain abstraction with a real world example. Say in your house you do have an electric plug and many devices can connect to the same plug but plug will never have an idea which device it is connected to, in other words the details of the devices is abstracted (hidden) to the plug.

Think what if we connect a device directly to electric wire without a plug? Say connect a bulb directly to a wire, then wire knows which device it is connected to and when ever we need to replace the bulb then we have to remove the wire connection from the bulb, which means bulb is tightly coupled with the wire. In other words bulb and wire knows the details where it is connected to, means not abstracted.

In object oriented world abstraction works exactly same. The class which consume other classes function/property doesn't need to know which classes function/property it is consuming and everything should be abstracted with an interface / abstract class.

Let me code the same example. Here I have a class "ElectricPlug", which is running a device. But the class "ElectricPlug" doesn't have any idea which device it is running. It can be any class implementing the interface "IDevice", which means the implementation of "RunDevice" is abstracted from "ElectricPlug". Here is the full sample code,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ElectricPlug electricPlug = new ElectricPlug(new Bulb());
    }
}

public class ElectricPlug
{
    private readonly IDevice _device;
    public ElectricPlug(IDevice device)
    {
        _device = device;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        _device.Rundevice();
    }
}


public interface IDevice
{
    void Rundevice();
}


public class Bulb : IDevice
{
    public void Rundevice()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Switched on bulb");
    }
}


public class ElectricPlug
{
    private readonly IDevice _device;
    public ElectricPlug(IDevice device)
    {
        _device = device;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        _device.Rundevice();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two parts of object in oops

- state   ( properties )
- behavior ( methods )

so to hiding the implementation of behavior of any object is known as abstraction

let's take a example -->
there is a cook at my home which makes delicious food . some body comes at my home and take dinner . after dinner they asked me that who made this food . i answered

- i have a cook whose name is tttt , his address is tttt and his number is 0000 ( these all are the properties of cook object )

they again asked how he made this then i answered

- i don't know how he made . i only know that he can make food

so abstraction means we are telling that what task our object can do instead of how my object can do a task .